# access swift Struct or class in Metal File

Tags: ios, swift, metal

In swift file, vertex data was declared:

```
struct Vertex {
    let position: vector_float4
    let color: vector_float4
}
```

I want to access this struct in metal file, is it possible?
if it is, how to make it?

I already know how to make it by Objective-C, just want to use swift.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to use the Swift struct directly from Metal. However, you could declare the struct in an Objective-C header and use it (via an Objective-C bridging header) in both Swift and Metal. Consult the Metal Game template provided with Xcode for an example of how to do this. Contrary to Apple's best practice recommendations, I actually prefer not to do this, and instead declare such structures in each of the respective languages.

The equivalent struct declaration in Metal Shading Language is

```
struct Vertex {
    float4 position;
    float4 color;
};
```

If you're using a vertex descriptor in your pipeline (with a `stage_in` parameter to the vertex function, as opposed to doing manual vertex fetch by taking in a `vertex_id` and a pointer to `Vertex` structs), you'll need to add attribute attributes to the struct, corresponding to their indices in the vertex descriptor attributes array. For example,

```
struct Vertex {
    float4 position [[attribute(0)]];
    float4 color [[attribute(1)]];
};
```

Comment: Yes, I agree with your preference, coding with metal is really not elegant

Comment: _Contrary to Apple's best practice recommendations, I actually prefer not to do this, and instead declare such structures in each of the respective languages._
Not a good idea, because the struct declared in Swift may not have the same memory layout. Technically he struct fields may even be re-ordered, even if that does not happen at the moment. There are not (yet) any directives in Swift to control memory struct layout.

Comment: Fair point. In almost five years of Swift churn, I have yet to be affected by that even once, but the possibility does remain.

Comment: @warrenm why do you prefer not to do it? Considering this leads to code duplication...

Comment: Because code duplication isn’t the only concern; the quality of the code matters too. Until Xcode 15, you had to use typedefs to reconcile the vector and matrix types, and you still have to use preprocessor gunk to deal with attributes. No thanks.

Comment: I'm coming back to this question after having tried sharing datatypes using a bridging header and I found it to be very messy using the preprocessor for Metal attributes so I went back to duplicating the types.